# Bootstrap Collapse Animation After Div Load

Tags: jquery

I'm using bootstrap & I'm loading my page contents with Click & Load events.

```
$("#Btn1").click(function () {
    $("#Panel1").load("Panel1.html");
});

$("#Btn2").click(function () {
    $("#Panel2").load("Panel2.html");
});

& ...
```

I'm loading each content in a collapse. I need the animation. The problem is that, animation is going to run before div loads complete. Page shrinks after div is loaded. I have tried multiple methods but not working any of them...

Comment: You can set the panels to be hidden as default, then load the html file and only after that it's been loaded - run an animation.